# How do I turn off minified JavaScript under Richfaces?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, richfaces, minify

For the purposes of debugging I need to make Richfaces use non-minified JavaScript. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A co-worker helped me out, posting this here for posterity. In the web.xml file add,

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Apparently this doesn't work for every script.